# How to specify hour in cron with range over midnight?

Tags: linux, cron

I need run a job every 15 minutes from 11 PM to 2 AM. I am using below range but its not working.

```
*/15 23,00-02 * * *
```

cron is ignoring the 23 and is running the job from 12AM ie 00.

Its in RedHat Enterprise Linux and its accepting ranges.

Comment: Have you tried putting them in ascending order?  `00-02,23` (or even `00,01,23`, as you don't want it running after 2am)

Comment: No i have not. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/cron-job-to-run-every-minute-from-11pm-to-6am

Comment: @Goro I used that answer(duplicate one) and it created the problem i stated in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me `*/15 00,01,23 * * *`